# Highcharts - Exporting options for print to match export to png

Tags: highcharts

How can I have exporting options for print match exactly the exporting options for png, jpg, etc.
Basically, I have a chart with the zoom features and I would like to remove the rangeSelector, navigator and scroll bar when a user selects to print.
I have set the exporting options like below, but it seems to only apply to exporting options that don't involve print.

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    scale: 3,
    fallbackToExportServer: false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using `beforePrint` event and updating the chart with new options. After that using `afterPrint`event update the chart with the old options.

Code:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      beforePrint: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.update({
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonTheme: {
              visibility: 'hidden'
            },
            labelStyle: {
              visibility: 'hidden'
            }
          },
          navigator: {
            enabled: false
          },
          scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }, true, false, false);
      },
      afterPrint: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.update({
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1,
            inputEnabled: true,
            buttonTheme: {
              visibility: 'visible'
            },
            labelStyle: {
              visibility: 'visible'
            }
          },
          navigator: {
            enabled: true
          },
          scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }, true, false, true);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/fs80h3qg/

**Api reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.beforePrint 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.afterPrint 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this but was hoping there was an options that would do it without modifying the original chart.